# Image not accessible inside the protected folder in Yii?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I am working in Yii.

I am trying to get an image which I have stored inside the `protected/members/img.jpg` 
but the image is not showing, however, I am trying to get the image when I put it outside the 
protected folder and it is getting displayed.

The `.htaccess` inside the protected folder has : `deny from all`

Is there something in it that I need to change to achieve what I am trying for??

Is there any method of getting the image which is stored inside the protected folder??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assetManagerFiles inside the "protected" folder are not accessible from the client browser. This prevents people to have access to important files, like your source code.

If you want to store images inside "protected" and want them to be accessible, you need to publish them using [CAssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager).

Usage is something like:

```
$path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/path-inside-protected';
$yourImageUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($path);
```

Yii will then use the file as an asset, coping it to the "assets" folder, sibling to "protected". After that, you can just use the url returned on your HTML.

```
<img src="<?php echo $yourImageUrl ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. However, I think this is the correct syntax : Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($path);

This is how I got it working.

Comment: Thats how it should be. Sorry about that. Answer was fixed.